# Publish a Python Notebook as an Azure Web Seriice

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone have a simple hello world Python Notebook that publishes as a web service

I attempted it and got all kinds of errors

```js
from azureml import services
#from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
services._DEBUG = True

#Use your own workspace information below!
workpace_id= '*****'
auth_token = '*****'

from azureml import services
@services.publish(workpace_id, auth_token)
@services.types()
@services.returns(str)
def myHello():
    return 'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at [this article](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-MachineLearning-ClientLibrary-Python)

> If the type information is not provided a Python specific format will be used and **other languages may not be able to call the sevice**.

Please also know that if return type is "str". You will get bytes values instead. Here is my result:
[image]